# View pager is overlapping the tab fragments vertically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using Viewpager to browse through the tabs. But my viewpager is overlapping the top of the fragment due to which the top of all the fagments are not visible. Adding padding on the top does the work but is there any better way to do it rather than giving padding on the next view.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/tabs">
   </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // ActionBar

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    // ViewPage: Slider that helps to create a page that we can swipe
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    tab.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    //Tablayout : Shows the tab bar that helps to find the ViewPager page
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(tab);

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't showing the whole XML. what kind of layout do you have them in? you can just put them both in a Linear Layout.

Comment: Relative Layout

Comment: @SaprativeJana check my answer. Hope it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have used Relative Layout and not  defined **android:layout_below="@id/appbar_layout"** . So I have edited your code. Just **copy and paste** below code in your xml file. It'll solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabs">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/appbar_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help you..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```